# Why does 十全十美 mean complete and beautiful?

Tags: meaning

Why does 十全十美 mean complete and beautiful ?
e.g. this dictionary meaning.
http://dictionary.writtenchinese.com/#sk=%E5%8D%81%E5%85%A8%E5%8D%81%E7%BE%8E&svt=pinyin

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were misled by the 美, thinking, naturally, it has something to do with a thing of beauty / being beautiful and so on. Not quite so as explained below.

First, "十", 10, here acts as a qualifier on 全 to indicate a 10 on a whole, (全), scale of 10.

In other words to describe a desired state of "perfection", "completeness", "flawless", i.e. 10 upon 10.

Like 他在每件事上都追求十全十美的结果 -- He seeks perfect results in all matters.

The 美, like "beautiful" in English usage has meanings beyond beautiful in looks; like 美妙, (wonderful), 美味, (delicious) So the 美 in 十全十美 indicates an absolutely positive, "beautiful", conclusion to whatever matters undertaken.

Answer (score 0):

That dictionary explains the missing part at http://dictionary.writtenchinese.com/worddetail/shi/645/1/1

It defines 十分 "to divide into ten equal parts / very / hundred percent / completely / extremely / utterly / absolutely."  That is, ten parts out of ten.

Answer (score 0):

十成 = 100%

"十" implies : 'complete/ totally'

全 = complete

美 = beautiful

十全十美 (totally complete, completely beautiful) = "**perfect**" , "f**lawless**"

Comment: 十成 is Ten percent, as per google translate.

Comment: Google translate got it wrong. 一成 is 10%, 九成九 is 99%. I have submitted a correction to it a moment ago.

Comment: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/746/ 成: [5] [n] one tenth; 10 per cent

Answer (score 0):

> complete and beautiful/to be perfect (idiom)

Please see the things right of the /. This meaning is used when you use full idiom.

That mean if you see it separately, it literally mean things left of the /. 全 have the meaning of complete while 美 have the meaning of beautiful.

You use 十全十美 to describe perfect things.